# Momentjs get time in current location

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I'm trying to generate a momentjs object of a certain timestamp in the current day of a specified location. For example:

```
  const timeNow = moment().tz('Africa/Cairo')
  const startTime = moment('10:00 am', 'HH:mm a')
  const endTime = moment('2:30 pm', 'HH:mm a')
```

Printing the above 3 variables outputs this:

```
Fri, 12:31 am
Thu, 10:00 am
Thu, 02:30 pm
```

Where the first result is in fact the current time in Cairo, However the other two results are the day before. How can I change it so that they return the current day?

Comment: `moment('10:00 am', 'HH:mm a').tz('Africa/Cairo');`?

Comment: @devanbuggay Yep that was it. I could have sworn I tried that but it didnt work. Thank you.

Comment: Please note that you can also set [default time zone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/), in your case, you can add `moment.tz.setDefault('Africa/Cairo')` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: @vincenzoc That's very helpful too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
moment.tz('Africa/Cairo') // <= Moment Object
```

**One small info:** whenever you'll get to see some javascript date in a browser that will be shown in your system's time-zone. As javascript Date is UTC, browsers will show accordingly. Use `moment.format()` to get string values.